# Filter over List with dynamic filter parameter

Tags: scala

If I had a

```
case class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var city: String)
```

and a list

```
val users = List(
  new User("Peter", "Fox", "Berlin"),
  new User("Otto",  "Schmidt", "Berlin"),
  new User("Carl",  "Schmidt", "Berlin"),
  new User("Hans",  "Schmidt", "Berlin"),
  new User("Hugo",  "Schmidt", "Berlin"))
```

define something

```
val test1 = (user:User,key:String) => user.lastName.equals(key)
val test2 = (user:User,key:String) => user.firstName.startsWith(key)
```

and filter

```
val test = users.filter(u => {
  test1(u,"Schmidt") && test2(u,"H")
})
```

This works fine. But How can I generate something that filters test1, test2 ... testn dynamicly form maybe a list? I want to have a lot of filter conditions predefined and combine them to one condition (like test1(u,"Schmidt") && test2(u,"H")) to filter my list and combine the order of filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you want is a way to compose predicates. A predicate in this case is a function that takes an User and returns a Boolean. So the type is just User => Boolean

First of all, I would reformulate your "predicate generator methods" so that you can generate predicates. Inside some helper object:

```
object UserPredicates {
  def lastNameEquals(value:String)(user:User) = user.lastName == value
  def firstNameStartsWith(value:String)(user:User) = user.firstName.startsWith(value)
  ..
}
```

To generate the predicate firstName starts with "H", you can partially apply the firstNameStartsWith method like so:

```
import UserPredicates._
val p1: User => Boolean = firstNameStartsWith("H")
```

Then it is pretty simple to create a predicate from multiple predicates by defining methods that compose predicates. Maybe also inside UserPredicates:

```
 def and(predicates:Seq[User => Boolean])(user:User) = predicates.forall(predicate => predicate(user))
 def or(predicates:Seq[User => Boolean)(user:User) = predicates.exists(predicate => predicate(user))
```

Then you can do

```
import UserPredicates._
val condition1 = firstNameStartsWith("H")
val condition2 = lastNameEquals("Schmidt")
val combined = and(Seq(condition1, condition2))
users.filter(combined)
```

Or short

```
users.filter(and(firstNameStartsWith("H"), lastNameEquals("Schmidt")))
```

.

By the way: you should not use new to create case class instances. Also, you don't have to use equals to compare strings. The scala == operator will call equals and not just check for reference equality like the java == operator.

Comment: With `def and(predicates: (User => Boolean)*)(user:User) =` you can probably get rid of `Seq` here: `and(condition1, condition2)`

Comment: I know. I could also simplify the combine predicates by using predicates.exists(_(user)) instead of predicates.exists(predicate => predicate(user)). But I thought it would be better to be a bit more verbose, otherwise it can get quite confusing for a scala beginner.

Comment: I wonder why not to use `User` methods `and(_.firstName.firstNameStartsWith("H"), ...)` without creating `UserPredicates`?

Comment: Of course you can do that. For something as simple as the given predicates it would be preferable. But I guess the firstNameStartsWith is just an example, and you might want some more complex predicates.

Comment: Some small adjustments: [`code`] val filterLastName = lastNameEquals("Schmidt")_ val filterFirstName = firstNameStartsWith("H")_ val combined = and(Seq(filterLastName,filterFirstName))_ for use it as partially applied function

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You can't edit comments after 5 minutes, so my previous comment ist ugly formatted and I'm doing it for the first time with code fragments.

Comment: super helpful for novice scala users! Amazed it has not been viewed more often

Answer (score 1):

I kind of like using implicits so you can get this kind of syntax:

```
  case class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var city: String)

  val users = List(
    new User("Peter", "Fox", "Berlin"),
    new User("Otto", "Schmidt", "Berlin"),
    new User("Carl", "Schmidt", "Berlin"),
    new User("Hans", "Schmidt", "Berlin"),
    new User("Hugo", "Schmidt", "Berlin"))

  //Note that these are curried now
  val filterLastName = (key: String) => (user: User) => user.lastName.equals(key)
  val filterFirstNameFirstChars = (key: String) => (user: User) => user.firstName.startsWith(key)

  implicit class FilterHelper[A](l: List[A]) {
    def filter(filters: List[A => Boolean]): List[A] = {
      l.filter(a => filters.forall(f => f(a)))
    }
  }

  //implicit filter takes a list of user predicates
  val test = users.filter(List(
    filterLastName("Schmidt"),
    filterFirstNameFirstChars("H")))
```